# Google chrome print content using Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a small HTML that i want to print on paper. It all works fine in Firefox but chrome tries to scale and fit and do stuff it shouldnt do and it messes up the whole layout. Is there way in chrome to mimic firefox printing or can i open a new window in firefox using chrome?

I currently have this code:

```
print(){
        var Printwindow = window.open("","","width=360,height=188");
        var cssFile = Printwindow.document.createElement("link");
        cssFile.rel = "stylesheet";
        cssFile.type = "text/css";
        cssFile.href = "../../content/label.css";

        Printwindow.document.write("<head>" + cssFile.outerHTML + "</head><body>" + this.label.innerHTML + "</body>");
        Printwindow.document.close();
        Printwindow.focus();

        Printwindow.print();
      //  Printwindow.close();
       //
```

Edit:

I discovered something interesting. THe printing window opens before the CSS styles are applied. If i close the print window, and then reopen it, then the layout is fine. How can i make sure that the print command is not called before the CSS is applied.

Comment: to help you they need your code,

Comment: @axelaxel what kind of code to you need? JS, HTML, CSS ? I feel like my question is not tied to a spesific piece of code, its more connected to browsers themselves.

Comment: The problem is most likely in the CSS. You probably should check if any media queries affect your print. Chrome has actually pretty good tools to test: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/print-preview

Comment: @DanielTorinao the print CSS is totally different from what is the print preview. But i fixed it by adding onload="window.print()" command. But now ... the print preview messes up few styles that were fine before the print preview. (emulation print is all fine, print preview is messed up).